# JSON schema with nested objects

Tags: json, dojo

I'm trying to validate some JSON objects using the [dojox JSON schema validator](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/json/schema.html) but I am new to this sort of thing and I can't get my schema right. I'm mostly trying to make sure that there aren't any missing fields in my objects.

Basically, I have an object that has two fields called type and description. The object can also have a properties field that contains any number of additional object fields. I put a little grammar representation below if that helps

Args : TYPE DESCRIPTION [Properties]

Properties : Args+

An example of my object looks like so:

```
{
        "type": "object",
        "description": "The point of interest location description.",
        "properties": {
            "pageIndex": {
                "type": "number",
                "description": "The page index to view"
            },
            "points": {
                "description": "Used if viewState.zoomWidth is true; specifies 4 corners of the rectangle to make visible.",
                "type": "array of point objects {x: y:}"
            },
            "viewState": {
                "type": "object",
                "description": "The view state information",
                "properties": {
                    "hasViewState": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "description": "Whether there is view state information to use"
                    },
                    "rotate": {
                        "type": "number",
                        "description": "Degrees of rotation"
                    },
                    "extents": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "description": "Whether the view should scale to fit extents or not"
                    },
                    "zoomWidth": {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "description": "Whether the view should scale to fit width or not"
                    },
                    "scaleFactor": {
                        "type": "number",
                        "description": "The scale factor for the view state"
                    },
                    "deviceRect": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "description": "The device rectangle geometry",
                        "properties": {
                            "left": {
                                "type": "number",
                                "description": "The left edge of the device rectangle"
                            },
                            "right": {
                                "type": "number",
                                "description": "The right edge of the device rectangle"
                            },
                            "top": {
                                "type": "number",
                                "description": "The top edge of the device rectangle"
                            },
                            "bottom": {
                                "type": "number",
                                "description": "The bottom edge of the device rectangle"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "eyePoint": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "description": "The eyepoint coordinate",
                        "properties": {
                            "x": {
                                "type": "number",
                                "description": "The x coordinate of the eyepoint"
                            },
                            "y": {
                                "type": "number",
                                "description": "The y coordinate of the eyepoint",
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I managed to make a schema that seems to be close but still doesn't validate it. This is what I tried
EDIT: it now seems to validate but it won't catch extra fields or missing fields

```
{
        "id" : "arg",
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
            "type" : { "type" : "string", "optional" : false },
            "description" : { "type" : "string", "optional" : false },
            "properties" : {
                "type" : "object",
                "patternProperties" : {
                    "[A-Za-z0-9]" : { "$ref" : "arg" }
                }
            }
        },
        "additionalProperties" : false
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try quotes around the keys in the dictionaries.

Comment: It validates now but its still a bit off

Comment: Ok so it works perfectly when i tested it out with this http://jsonschemalint.com/ but doesn't work with the dojox JSON tool